# Force download .xls file in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/download/{id}/{filename}', function($id, $filename)
    {
        // Check if file exists in app/storage/file folder
        $file_path = storage_path() .'/orders/'.'/'.$id.'/'. $filename;
        if (file_exists($file_path))
        {

            // Send Download
            return Response::download($file_path, $filename, [
                'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Error
            exit('Requested file does not exist on our server!');
        }
    })->where('filename', '[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\.]+');
```

That downloads an excel file form /app/storage in Laravel (previously uploaded).
The problem I'm facing is that the downloaded excel file is unreadable by excel. If I download the uploaded file from FTP it's ok. I tried all types of headers for Content-Type but nothing seems to work. Is there a special header for excel files?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code in CI please find helper file or library for Laravel

```
$this->load->helper('download');
if(file_exists("user_files/test.txt")){
    $data = file_get_contents("user_files/test.txt");
    force_download("test.txt", $data);
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```